# disable double tap on UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a way to disable the double tap on UITabBarItem?

Basically I'm pushing a new view over the log-in page and I don't want to allow the user to be able to go back by tapping the tab twice.

Once the user signed in successfully there is no need for the log-in page anymore.

I do the push like this

```
VC *somevc = [[VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:somevc animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
[seomvc release];
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your VC class’s `-viewDidAppear:animated:`, you can do something like this:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self] animated:YES];
```

and thereby remove the login screen from the navigation stack entirely. Tapping the tab bar icon will still return to the root view controller—that’s expected behavior, and you should avoid disabling it without good reason—but the root view controller will now be your `somevc` instead of the login page.

Comment: The above code crashed the app. Here's more info. In the app delegate I create a tabbarcontroller out of an array of uinavigationcontroller. One uinavcontroller for each tab in the app. One of the tab is that I'm having problem with

Comment: I have added this code above it and now it's working? Any idea why? NSMutableArray *views = [[[self navigationController] viewControllers] mutableCopy]; But will crash again if I release views.

Comment: The app crashed because I had two viewcontroller loaded into the navcontroller but the array had only one item. added nil object and it;s good now